# (Python) Encontrar palavras com o total de vogais sendo par

Tags: python, string

Gostaria de pedir a ajuda de vocês. Tenho um código em Python onde falta uma parte: analisar as palavras de uma frase e guardar as que tenham número par de vogais.

Exemplo: "Cheguei em casa e fui jogar videogame". A palavra "Cheguei" tem 4 vogais, 4 é par então preciso guardá-la em uma lista.

Quero fazer isso com todas as frases lidas e depois reescrevê-las dentro da lista.

Código incompleto:

```
def frases():
vog="aeiou"
dig="0123456789"
sd=0
sv=0
vp=[]

f = str(input('Digite uma frase: ')).lower()

while f != '':
    vp = f.split()

    for a in range(len(vp)):
        for l in vp[a]:
            if l in vog:
                sv+=1

        for d in vp[a]:
            if d in dig:
                sd += 1

    print('Palavras contidas na frase: {}'.format(len(vp)))
    print('Total de vogais: {}'.format(sv))
    print('Total de dígitos: {}'.format(sd))
    print()

        f = str(input('Digite uma frase: ')).lower()


frases()
```

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isso te ajuda.

```
def frases():
    vog="aeiou"
    dig="0123456789"
    sd=0
    sv=0
    vp=[]
    matriz_palavras_vogais_pares = []

    f = str(input('Digite uma frase: ')).lower()

    while f != '':

        palavras_vogais_pares = []
        vogais_na_frase = 0
        digitos_na_frase = 0

        vp = f.split()

        for palavra in vp:
            vogais = 0
            digitos = 0
            for letra in palavra:
                if letra in vog:
                    vogais += 1
                if letra in dig:
                    digitos += 1

            vogais_na_frase += vogais
            digitos_na_frase += digitos

            sv += vogais
            sd += digitos

            if vogais %2 == 0: #Ou ainda if (vogais %2 == 0) and (palavra not in palavras_vogais_pares):
                palavras_vogais_pares.append(palavra)

        matriz_palavras_vogais_pares.append(palavras_vogais_pares)

        print('Palavras contidas na frase: {}'.format(len(vp)))
        print('Total de vogais nessa frase: {}'.format(vogais_na_frase))
        print('Total de dígitos nessa frase: {}'.format(digitos_na_frase))
        print('Total de vogais: {}'.format(sv))
        print('Total de dígitos: {}'.format(sd))
        print('Palavras com número par de vogais: {}'.format(palavras_vogais_pares))
        print('Todas as palavras: {}'.format(matriz_palavras_vogais_pares))
        print()


        f = str(input('Digite uma frase: ')).lower()
```

Comment: Foi quase, o problema é que ele adiciona palavras que não tem nenhuma vogal. Faça o teste se você quiser, exemplo de frase "ligue para 2444-5000",  Ele vai adicionar até o número na lista.

Comment: @user122202 veja agora com a edição. Caso voce queira adicionar palavras sem repetí-las, pode ainda adicionar `and palavra not in palavras_vogais_pares`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Único problema agora é que o a lista(palavras_vogais_pares) contem as palavras com vogais par de todas as frases. Eu precisaria de uma lista para cada. Exemplo: lista1 com as palavras com vogais  da 1º frase. lista2 com as palavras da 2º frase.

Comment: @user122202 pesquise sobre matrizes então.

Answer (score 1):

Regex costuma ser uma ferramenta muito útil para esse tipo de coisa.
Como já há uma resposta que segue a estrutura do seu código aqui vai uma usando apenas regex e considerando apenas vogais e consoantes presentes em português.

```
import re
    f = '.'
    while f != '':
        f = str(input('Digite uma frase ou pressione enter para sair: ')).lower()
        print('Palavras contidas na frase: {}'.format(len(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b',f))))
        v_br=r'[aáãâàéeiíoóõúu]'
        c_br=r'[b-dçf-hj-np-tv-z]'
        v2_br = r'(\b(?:'+c_br+r'*'+v_br+c_br+r'*'+v_br+c_br+r'*)+\b)'
        rv = re.compile(v_br, re.UNICODE)
        r2v = re.compile(v2_br, re.UNICODE)
        p2v = re.findall(r2v,f)
        print('Total de vogais nessa frase: {}'.format(len(re.findall(v_br,f))))
        print('Total de dígitos nessa frase: {}'.format(len(re.findall(r'\d',f))))
        print('Palavras com número par de vogais: {}'.format(str(len(p2v))+", "+str(p2v)))
```

Comment: Interessante, mas pra mim que sou muito iniciante ficou confuso kkk. No entanto saberia me dizer se tem como criar uma matriz com tamanho indefinida, assim como as listas? exemplo: lista=[] matriz=??

Comment: Não se assuste. Regex parece muito estranho mesmo à primeira vista. Até onde eu saiba em python uma matriz é simplesmente uma lista de lista. Para nenhuma das duas é necessário pré-definir o tamanho, mas não vejo relação de uma coisa com outra...

Answer (score 0):

Código atualizado, mas incompleto:

```
def frases():
vog="aáãâàéeiíoóõúu"
dig="0123456789"
sd=0
sv=0
vp=[]
vtp=[]
vtv=[]
vtd=[]
vpp=[]

f = str(input('Digite uma frase ou pressione enter para terminar: ')).lower()
vp = f.split()
vtp.append(len(vp))

for p in vp:
    v = 0
    d = 0
    for l in p:
        if l in vog:
            v += 1
        if l in dig:
            d += 1
    sv += v
    sd += d

vtv.append(sv)
vtd.append(sd)
v=0
d=0
sv=0
sd=0

while f != '':
    f = str(input('Digite uma frase ou pressione enter para terminar: ')).lower()
    vp = f.split()
    vtp.append(len(vp))

    for p in vp:
        v = 0
        d = 0
        for l in p:
            if l in vog:
                v += 1
            if l in dig:
                d += 1
        sv += v
        sd += d

    vtv.append(sv)
    vtd.append(sd)
    v=0
    d=0
    sv=0
    sd=0

for i in range(len(vtp)-1):
    print()
    print('Palavras contidas na {}º frase: {}'.format(i+1, vtp[i]))
    print('Total de vogais na {}º frase: {}'.format(i+1, vtv[i]))
    print('Total de dígitos na {}º: {}'.format(i+1, vtd[i]))
    print()
```

frases()

Preciso melhorar essa parte:

```
if v %2 == 0 and v != 0 and p not in vpp:
 vpp.append(p)
if len(vpp) > 0:
for i in range(len(vpp)-1):
    print('Palavras com número par de vogais da {}º frase: {}'.format(i+1, vpp[i]))
```

Eu precisaria de uma lista para cada frase. Exemplo: 
lista1 = palavras com vogais par da 1º frase. 
lista2 = palavras com vogais par da 2º frase.
etc...